# Il gioco non ne valeva la candela

Tags: meaning, idioms, phrase-origin

Buongiorno,

Qualcuno potrebbe dirmi da dove deriva l'espressione "il gioco non ne vale la candela". La candela, in questa espressione, a cosa si riferisce?

Grazie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questa locuzione si utilizza per indicare il dubbio che il guadagno nel fare o per ottenere qualcosa non valga lo sforzo o la spesa da effettuare; la "candela" si riferisce proprio alla candela nel senso del lume. Prendo la spiegazione da [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Il_gioco_non_vale_la_candela)

> Questa espressione è di origine medievale [...]. A quei tempi era necessario usare candele o lampade ad olio per qualunque attività notturna e il costo delle candele, specialmente per le classi sociali più basse, poteva diventare una spesa considerevole. Era quindi consuetudine, per i giocatori di carte, lasciare una piccola somma (o a volte una vera e propria candela) al proprietario della casa che li ospitava o all'oste della locanda.